# How to use IntelliJ Idea 13 Ultimate file watcher for compiling scss files to css?

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

I am trying to use IntelliJ Idea to translate some scss files to css but I am getting strange errors from Tomcat Catalina log (WARNING: Scss file VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.scss exists but ScssStylesheet was not able to find it)

Here is an image with the File Watcher settings :

[image]

And here is an image with my files :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that file watchers is not the correct solution for IntelliJ Idea 13 since the intellij idea vaadin plugin is compatible with IntelliJ Idea 12.
So to have the scss files get compiled I thought of a workaround that uses the vaadin-maven-plugin.
You can read the whole article I have written to my blog in this link :

http://blog.devcanvas.org/?p=484

In short the user must run a maven goal (vaadin:compile-theme) and set it to run before make.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure about your server error, but my configuration requires some Enviroment variables and an absolute path to scss.bat to performe an complete compilation.

In my case:

//where my ruby installation is found

## Program:

C:\Ruby200\bin\scss.bat

## Enviroment variables:

PATH=C:\Ruby200\bin

Comment: scss is already on the path and I can executed from terminal and from all the system directories.If I change into style.scss directory and do a 'sass styles.scss styles.css' I get the following error (Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../reindeer/reindeer.scss) and that is normal because the above reindeer.scss is imported in the maven project as a maven dependency only.